# Why receiving "ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row" in this case?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I created a view named MANAGERS_SUPERUSERS by joining 3 tables ( USERS, SITES AND users_site_access_level) so that I can query the view to retrieve
a table for each site, the city, state, managers, site users etc. when i executed the code to retrieve, sql developer threw an error "ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row" at me.Below is the code i executed to return the desired attributes:

```
SELECT CUSTOMER
,LONG_NAME
,(SELECT MANAGER_SITEUSER FROM MANAGERS_SUPERUSERS WHERE ACCESS_LEVEL_ID = 25)MANAGERS
,(SELECT MANAGER_SITEUSER FROM MANAGERS_SUPERUSERS WHERE ACCESS_LEVEL_ID = 24)SITEUSERS
,CITY
,STATE
,LMS_GL_CODE
FROM  MANAGERS_SUPERUSERS;
```

the code executed to create the view is as follows:

```
CREATE VIEW MANAGERS_SUPERUSERS AS
SELECT CUSTOMER,LONG_NAME,CITY,STATE,LMS_GL_CODE,FNAME  || ' ' || LNAME As "MANAGER_SITEUSER",T.UPDATE_DT,ACCESS_LEVEL_ID
FROM 
(SELECT *
  FROM USERS
  INNER JOIN SITES ON  USERS.DFLT_SITE_ID  =SITES.SITE_ID
  LEFT JOIN users_site_access_level ON users_site_access_level.USER_ID=USERS.USER_ID
WHERE ACCESS_LEVEL_ID IN (24,25))T;
```

Can someone help me troubleshoot this query?

Comment: See my answer, but I see here the major logical flaw. You seem trying to use correlated sub query where you really should use a join. Because you can't have many records subquery into one.

Answer (score 0):

Seems likely that the problem is these two lines:

```
,(SELECT MANAGER_SITEUSER FROM MANAGERS_SUPERUSERS WHERE ACCESS_LEVEL_ID = 25)MANAGERS
,(SELECT MANAGER_SITEUSER FROM MANAGERS_SUPERUSERS WHERE ACCESS_LEVEL_ID = 24)SITEUSERS
```

What you are trying to do there is called a scalar subquery, and it has to return exactly one column and one row for each row returned by your query.  It seems likely they are returning multiple rows, causing the error.

What is the piece of information you are trying to get with those subqueries?  Are you trying to show whether the user represented by the current row is a manager or superuser for the site?

Maybe what you want is this, but it's just a guess at this point:

```
SELECT CUSTOMER
,LONG_NAME
,CASE WHEN ACCESS_LEVEL_ID = 25 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END ) IS_MANAGER,
,CASE WHEN ACCESS_LEVEL_ID = 24 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END ) IS_SUPERUSER,
,CITY
,STATE
,LMS_GL_CODE
FROM  MANAGERS_SUPERUSERS;
```

I also wonder if in the view, the join to USERS_SITE_ACCESS_LEVEL should incorporate the SITE_ID as well as the USER_ID.  The name of the table seems to imply that a single user could have different access to different sites.

Comment: I really appreciate your time and effort to help me on this challenge.
I would like to create a query to extract the following 
• CUSTOMER
• LONG_NAME
• CITY
• STATE
• LMS_GL_CODE
• General Manager( DERIVED COLUMN (concatenate first and last name))
• Site User(DERIVED COLUMN DERIVED COLUMN (concatenate first and last name))
• UPDATE_DT
FROM THE FOLLOWING TABLE:

1. USERS: (USER_ID,USERNAME,PASSWRD,FNAME,LNAME,IS_ACTIVE,DFLT_SITE_ID,SUPE_USER_ID,LAST_LOGIN,EMAIL,CLOCK_NUM,CREATE_DT,CREATE_USER_ID,UPDATE_DT,UPDATE_USER_ID, SHIFT_ID)

Comment: 2. SITES
(SITE_ID,SHORT_NAME,LONG_NAME,CUSTOMER,CITY,STATE,CAMPUS,COUNTRY,PHP_TIMEZONE,CI_TIMEZONE,MYSQL_TIME_ZONE,LMS_CONNECTION_AVAILABLE,LMS_HOSTNAME,LMS_USERNAME,LMS_PASSWORD,LMS_DATABASE,LMS_WH_ID,LMS_GL_CODE,LMS_AUTO_UPDATE_ENABLED,MYLIFT_ENABLED,MYTIME_CANCEL_EMAIL_ENABLED,UPDATE_DT,UPDATE_USER_ID,CREATE_DT,CREATE_USER_ID,LMS_RECORDTYPE,PARENT_SITE_ID)

Comment: 3. USERS_SITE_ACCESS _LEVELS
(ID, USER_ID, SITE_ID, ACCESS_LEVEL_ID, UPDATE_DT, UPDATE_USER_ID)
How do I approach this task?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here

```
...
, (SELECT MANAGER_SITEUSER FROM MANAGERS_SUPERUSERS WHERE ACCESS_LEVEL_ID = 25)MANAGERS
,(SELECT MANAGER_SITEUSER FROM MANAGERS_SUPERUSERS WHERE ACCESS_LEVEL_ID = 24)SITEUSERS...
```

What happening, your statement returns more than 1 value per record and this is error.

You need to add a condition to identify specific record like this :

```
SELECT CUSTOMER
,LONG_NAME
,(SELECT MANAGER_SITEUSER 
  FROM MANAGERS_SUPERUSERS ms 
  WHERE ms.<id_column> = msuper.<id_column> And msuper.ACCESS_LEVEL_ID = 25) MANAGERS
,(SELECT MANAGER_SITEUSER 
  FROM MANAGERS_SUPERUSERS ms 
  WHERE ms.<id_column> = msuper.<id_column> And msuper.ACCESS_LEVEL_ID = 24 ) SITEUSERS
,CITY
,STATE
,LMS_GL_CODE
FROM  MANAGERS_SUPERUSERS msuper;
```

Note that Place emphasis on `ms.<id_colimn> = msuper.<id_column>` and only then `msuper.ACCESS_LEVEL_ID = 24` 
In other words, you need to link a record you retrieving in your subquery `MANAGER_SITEUSER` to your main record of `MANAGERS_SUPERUSERS`.

But you know, these correlated subqueries are expensive. You could get away with multiple joins.

**NOTE** My answer is telling you why you having this issue. And to achieve this you need to rework your view, etc. Looking at your question closely, I see some disconnect between the view structure and attempt of querying it. May be the answer provided by Dave Costa is more appropriate in this situation

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't in your view but instead in what you're using to query the view.  The subqueries for managers and siteusers are likely bringing back more than one row.

Comment: I need help writing pl sql query to extract information from 3 tables

I really appreciate your time and effort to help me on this challenge.
I would like to create a query to extract the following 
• CUSTOMER
• LONG_NAME
• CITY
• STATE
• LMS_GL_CODE
• General Manager( DERIVED COLUMN)
• Site User(DERIVED COLUMN)
• UPDATE_DT

Comment: FROM THE FOLLOWING TABLE:l

USERS:
• USER_ID
• USERNAME
• PASSWRD
• FNAME
• LNAME
• IS_ACTIVE
• DFLT_SITE_ID
• SUPE_USER_ID
• LAST_LOGIN
• EMAIL
• CLOCK_NUM
• CREATE_DT
• CREATE_USER_ID
• UPDATE_DT
• UPDATE_USER_ID
• SHIFT_ID
SITES
• SITE_ID
• SHORT_NAME
• LONG_NAME
• CUSTOMER
• CITY
• STATE
• CAMPUS
• COUNTRY
• PHP_TIMEZONE
• CI_TIMEZONE
• MYSQL_TIME_ZONE
• LMS_CONNECTION_AVAILABLE
• LMS_HOSTNAME
• LMS_USERNAME
• LMS_PASSWORD
• LMS_DATABASE

Comment: • LMS_WH_ID
• LMS_GL_CODE
• LMS_AUTO_UPDATE_ENABLED
• MYLIFT_ENABLED
• MYTIME_CANCEL_EMAIL_ENABLED
• UPDATE_DT
• UPDATE_USER_ID
• CREATE_DT
• CREATE_USER_ID
• LMS_RECORDTYPE
• PARENT_SITE_ID
USERS_SITE_ACCESS _LEVELS
• ID
• USER_ID
• SITE_ID
• ACCESS_LEVEL_ID
• UPDATE_DT
• UPDATE_USER_ID
How do I approach this task?